# What is this extra row of seats on American Airlines flights?

Tags: air-travel, aircraft, seating

This flight check-in page allows you to choose seats from a 'row 34' which is shown in front of all the other rows and with 9 seats.

Is this just for overbooking? What are these seats like?

[image: seatplan]

The plane is an American Airlines MD-80

Comment: Take a seat at the font, this plane is so quite at the front, and so noisy at the back. The ugliest plane was ever made in history.

Answer (score 7):

According to [SeatGuru](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/American_Airlines/American_Airlines_MD-80_B_new.php) this row doesn't exist. I'd suspect a bug in the booking software, and wouldn't book a seat in this phantom row if I were you :)

Comment: I have worked in a variation of this ugly plane for 7 years, what you said is correct, it is 100% a bug. The extra row shown belongs to a wide-bodied plane, most likely a 777-200.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis either that, or they are some new kind of super-tiny jump seat that can fit nine passengers in the width of five normal seats, between the buklhead and/or flight attendants and the first row of normal-seat passengers.  US air carriers are known for squeezing revenue, after all.

Comment: @phoog I do not think so, check the 777-200 v1 for American Airlines and you will see a match with the extra row the OP posted.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis it was a joke :-)

Comment: @phoog LOL, actually this plane is joke, so anything is possible ;)

Comment: I would still like to know what happens when you book them, what is printed on the ticket, what is registered in the system, what is printed on the seating list the crew gets, and how the crew handle it when you ask for some help finding your seat ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper "Sorry sir, there was a mistake, you can not board. Here's a voucher!"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The above screenshot is actually mine. Choosing seat 34G bumped me to 22E on the next page and eventual ticket, probably because that's the first seat with a similar cost.